# iPhone 6: battery replacement and display problem

Tags: iphone, display, battery

I'm planning to have a battery replacement procedure for my old iPhone 6. However, at the same time, I'm also experiencing another problem with it: the bottom of the display seems like not to be fully glued any more - there feels a bit of looseness and some very minimal freedom. I understand it's a sort of common problem for old devices, like adhesives did dry out, or something like that.

Now, my question is the following: while replacing the battery, will they also remove the display? And then like put it back?

I mean, is it possible that they would fix this display issue at the same time while replacing the battery? Or is it a completely unrelated maintenance, and I should order/pay separately for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they replace the battery, they have to completely remove the display. If it is an iPhone 6, there actually isn't any adhesive between the display and the enclosure. It is possible to two screws at the bottom are loose, and when they put the display back on, they will tighten those. I would just mention the display problem when you drop it off for the battery. They should at least be able to tell if it's the screws or something more advanced.

Comment: I see, thank you! (I will be able to accept it as an answer after 9 minutes, it tells me :)